# Push by user to mercurial repository causes http 500 error for other users

Tags: mercurial, corrupt

I have a windows hosted mercurial repository that UserA, UserB and UserC have rights to push to.  UserA can happily push/pull etc...but once UserC pushes...UserA starts to receive the following error:

abort: HTTP Error 500: .hg\store\data/_web/_mvc._sitemap.i: Access is denied

The only 'fix' for this is to nuke and re init the remote repository.

Does anyone have any experience with this type of issue?

**Update:**
Repository is sitting on a drive on the server with IIS sitting on top of it. Users connect locally.  Setup is pretty much right of the Mercurial wiki.

Comment: Provide more details on the mercurial server. How it is has been setup. How users access it ...

Comment: I updated the question for clarity.

Comment: It's a permission problem, when C pushes the files he adds do not have the right permissions, this means the web server can't accesss them.

Comment: And tonfa continues his campaign of putting right answers in comments so people can't pick them. ;)

Comment: Ok but why?  Does UserC need to do anything to their local repository? The files that UserA pushes don't seem to have the issue, and UserB and UserC can push fine after UserA has pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm putting tonfa's answer down here with a little extra info.  This is completely normal, and really just how file systems work.  When your users are pushing with direct disk access they're creating new files that are owned by them.  Unless steps are taken to make sure those files owned by them are also writeable by their collaborators then subsequent pushers (and pullers depending on your default permissions) will be told they can't access the newly created files.

There are a few general ways to avoid this *all of which are the server administrator's job not the pushing users's job*.  Either:

- change permissions so that all new files are automatically added with permissions that allow all collaborators read/write access
- make everyone use only the HTTP interface for pushing/pulling so all read/writes are done by the same (IIS) user

In unix land the former is easy to do using the "sticky group bit" and a "umask".  On windows there's probably an even easier way that works only half the time. ;)

Comment: Everyone was using the HTTP interface so that was weird and why it didn't seem to work well.  What I've done and seems to be working is change the owner of the .hg and subfolders to the Users group of the server.  Thanks a ton...would have sworn that going through HTTP and the single IIS user would have been ok but apparently not.

Comment: It's a dim recollection, but I think Mercurial uses the permissions of the .hg/store directory itself as the permissions of any new files it creates (ANDed with the inverse of the umask on *nix), so if the .hg/store was originally created w/ non-group friendly perms that could have made the difference.  That may explain you your correcting the .hg subfolders fixed things.  Anyway, glad it's good to go for you now.